# Запрос к бд при вложенных классах Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, hql

Ecть два класса:

```
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "A")
public class A{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", length = 16, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String name;
}
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", length = 16, unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_Id", nullable = false)
    private A a;
}
```

Для запросов к бд создан интерфейс

```
public interface B extends JpaRepository<B, UUID> {
}
```

Нужен запрос что-то вроде:

```
    @Query("SELECT b FROM B b WHERE b.a_Id = :a")
    Set<B> findA(@Param("a") A a);
```

```
или
```

```
    @Query("SELECT b FROM B b WHERE b.a_Id = :a")
    Set<B> findA(@Param("a") UUID a);
```

оба не работают.
Можно ли как-то реализовать такую выборку по вложенному классу?

Comment: создайте OneToMany в первой сущности ко второй сущности. Будет эквивалент вашему запросу

Comment: тоже вариант, спасибо!

еще есть вот такое способ и он работает
Set<B> findByA_id(UUID id);

А есть ли возможность выводить не список классов В, а например, список B.a.name - список имен класса А? (не меняя класс А)

Comment: Что вам мешает получить список, а из него вытащить только `name` и сформировать из них новый список?